# RPC in rabbitmq: How to return exceptions to client

Tags: exception, grails, rabbitmq, rpc

I want to implement RPC over RabbitMQ. Consumer can produce exceptions. How the consumer should return these exceptions? Is there any header I could use to tag the result as an exception?

In particular, I am using it in the rabbitmq-native plugin for grails 3.0.9.

Comment: There are no headers for this. You will have to mark success/failure as part of your request reply